# contenteditable div changes font size on pressing Backspace key

Tags: html, contenteditable

Placing a cursor inside a contenteditable div, pressing Enter and then pressing Backspace on keyboard - changes font size bellow the cursor.

Why this happens and is there a way to prevent it.

I tried to reproduce this problem using code snippets but it seams it's working normally here.

```html
    <div class='divedit' id='divstory' contenteditable>
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the circumstances (e.g. browser, version...)

Comment: You're problem is not reproducable. You need to provide a reproducable problem.

Comment: @LaurIvan, I'm using Chrome, and tested in Opera - the same problem exists.

Comment: @puerto have you tried to use something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)?